# Not able to set JSON web token in Cookie of browser

Tags: angular, express

I have been struggling to set JSON web token in my browser’s cookie through my Express JS Server.

My application consists of below layers

Front End built on-------> Angular 5  (Running Port 4200)

Backend built on --------> Node JS and Express. (Running Port 3000)

Database -----------------> Mongo DB.

My login functionality authenticates where in I generate a JSON web token from my Express JS server and then send it back to angular client.I am able to store it in localStoarge and sessionStorage but the only problem is if I try to store it in Browser's cookie it doesn't .

I read many links where it suggests many things but did not seem to be working in my case.

After successful authentication I get the cookie in response header as below but don't see it under Application tab---> Cookie.
I have spent almost a week identifying it but still don't get what is the problem.Please help me out.

**Response Header**

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept ,Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 602
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 23 Jul 2018 14:58:28 GMT
ETag: W/"25a-uOkndftxIROaCsWCqopW7OD3LhQ"
**Set-Cookie: SESSIONID=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE1MzIzNTc5MDgsImV4cCI6MTUzMjM1ODIwOH0.VH3jV3XPo6xXNGcVScqOjbz1SUtvEieCQoqB4PhRsfNtqJn51PO3Jv-imUkByKo0Y2GPkh_7lLdNWOequhFibHWMD9bWyC7umRqraVmlNjx0_JIwQ4Cd6J4lVyJrKj6B9MfUrJPIT9YmUhwUR4f5otNMP2ujet9tV439KwpKbsfpw6IXgonbKb8Q0Bc431Z2YzzWcRv3EE4rimcazGA2je8hMea3XjecHkrMtTgQFc83Rk5mDhDhby0o-pUzjDURu6v5S4XjbeWLO2bishgqTHKX4Rtc1D1AJgJntKxBUUbjIkY1yrkzQvNwnB4XE8u9RU_O102TJKv7QKZbVtFGSQ; Max-Age=300; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 23 Jul 2018 15:03:28 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure**

Is this a CORS related issue or something to do with my browser.
I am but confused as same behaviour is on Chrome as well as FireFox browser.

My angular service authentication code is as below

return this.http.post(url,obj);

Somewhere I read about withCredentials:true 
Is this the reason behind not setting the cookie ?

Comment: We are going to see your Node code and how you set the cookie in the response. This is an `HttpOnly` cookie, so front-end code is completely unable to touch it.

Comment: My Express Js code is   res.cookie('SESSIONID',token,{ maxAge: tokenExpiry*1000,
               httpOnly:true,secure:true});